# Segmentation fault(core dumped) with C++ on ubuntu

Tags: c++

I implemented a red black tree but when I run the program from the terminal, it gives the error: Segmentation fault core dumped. I think that I 'm accessing a location that I shouldn't be accessing or I'm accessing something null.

This is my insert method:

```
template <class Item, class Key>
void RedBlackTree<Item, Key>::Insert(RedBlackTree<Item,Key> Tree, Node<Item, Key> *z)
{
    Node <Item, Key> *T=0;
    Node<Item, Key>* nill=T->nill;
    Node<Item, Key>* root=T->root;
    Node<Item, Key> *y;
    Node<Item, Key> *x;

    y=nill;
    x=root;
    //x= T->getRoot();

    while(x != nill)
    {
        y=x;
         if(z->getKey() < x->getKey())
             x= x->getLeft();
         else
             x = x->getRight();
    }

    z->setParent(y);

    if(y == nill)
        z=T->root;
    else
    if((z->getKey())<(y->getKey()))
    {
        y->setLeft(z);
    }
    else
    {
        y->setRight(z);
    }
        z->setLeft(nill);
        z->setRight(nill);
        z->colour1 = 'R';
        FixingInsert(Tree,z);
}
```

This is part of my main:

```
Node<int, int> q = Node<int, int>(0,5);

RedBlackTree<int, int> tree1;


    tree1.Insert(tree1, &q);
```

Can anyone help please? I am new to templates and I would really appreciate if someone helps me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would compile/run with debug options, so that you see the stacktrace, and better track the exception.

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: I recommend http://cgdb.github.io/

Comment: I do not see a line that initializes the variable `T` to point to some instance of the class before first use.

Answer (score 4):

You are dereferencing the NULL-pointer (twice!):

```
Node <Item, Key> *T=0;
Node<Item, Key>* nill=T->nill;
Node<Item, Key>* root=T->root;
```

I have a feeling you wanted to write:

```
RedBlackTree <Item, Key> *T= &Tree;
Node<Item, Key>* nill=T->nill;
Node<Item, Key>* root=T->root;
```

or

```
RedBlackTree <Item, Key> *T= this;
Node<Item, Key>* nill=T->nill;
Node<Item, Key>* root=T->root;
```

Although both would be redundant, because you already have the pointer in `this` (but you can access the member variables directly anyway) and you already have the object `Tree` whose members you can access via `Tree.`, too (as long as they are `public`).

Also why do you pass a *copy* of the object to a method of itself? This is completely unnecessary. Even a reference would be redundant.

You probably should remove the `Tree` parameter, remove the line `Node <Item, Key> *T=0;` and remove all `T->`.

Comment: I tried to use:Node <Item, Key> *T= &Tree; but it gives the error: cannot convert ‘RedBlackTree<int, int>*’ to ‘Node<int, int>*’ in initialization

Comment: @user3136756 Well I don't know the declaration of `RedBlackTree` and `Node` as you haven't posted them. I only guessed what might be correct, however I cannot know.

Comment: I have all my getters, setters, node members such as left, parent, right, root and nill declared in Node header file.

Comment: @user3136756 Still I don't know what you have written in there, also this doesn't seem to be part of the original question anymore.